# PHP parse_ini_file work on URL?

Tags: php, ini

Does the PHP method **parse_ini_file** work on an INI file hosted in the cloud?  Right now, I have a config file that sits in every single one of my App servers, which could be anywhere from 4-8 at any given time.  Making a config change is brutally painful to do by hand for each server.

I've tried the following but to no avail:

```
$handle = fopen('https://blah.com/config.ini', 'r');
$ini = parse_ini_file($handle, true);
```

but I get this error:

```
Warning: parse_ini_file() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, resource given
```

Is this even possible?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fopen()` is not used like that.  Try [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/file_get_contents):

```
$content = file_get_contents('https://blah.com/config.ini');
$ini = parse_ini_string($content, true);
```

This may work instead (not tested):

```
$ini = parse_ini_file('https://blah.com/config.ini', true);
```

In either case `allow_url_fopen` needs to be enabled in `php.ini`.

Comment: This wouldn't still work because `parse_ini_file()` expects a **file path**. Use `parse_ini_string()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Fopen returns a pointer to the file, and parse_ini_file accepts file path and opens the file itself.

You should try and use file_get_contents() to get data from the file, which you then pass to parse_ini_string() function which is the same as parse_ini_file() but it takes ini file in a string.